# Jump to definitions in eclipse doesnt work

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to java development and eclipse IDE. All this time I use IDE like PHPStorm and Visual Studio Code. And in those IDE we have `Ctrl + Click` shortcut to jump to definition of the class/functions. I know in eclipse there is the shortcut for that too. But in my case, it doesn't work..

[image: error]
Please can somebody tell me what should i do to make this shortcut works.. because it will HELP ME A LOT to see the properties and methods inside the class.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not that the jump doesn't work, but that you don't have the source attached.

In your case it looks like you want the source for Tomcat 7.0 servlet-api You can download that from Maven central http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.94/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.94-sources.jar

Then click the Attach Source button and browse to the jar you downloaded, and it should work.

Note: I don't know the exact version (ie. 7.0.???) you have so you might need to get a different  source jar if that one doesn't match.

Comment: I do have servlet-api.jar when I downloaded the tomcat. [image](http://prntscr.com/nrqvof)

Comment: Yes you do. You have `tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.94.jar` (equivalent) which is fine, but it doesn't include the source (which you apparently want to see) for which you need `tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.94-sources.jar`. In your exact case it appear the jars are slightly renamed and the exact version i'm not sure of so you will need to adjust as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn'tfind the Source Code of `HttpServlet` (in `servlet-api.jar`). If you want to see it, you should download the Sources and attach them.